# Help me find a component based on its label

Tags: components, identification

I have an SMD component containing two pads. There is a label on the surface of the component: 200A in one row and 06A in second row. I suppose the component is a diode but I don't know what kind and how I can buy it.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a Vishay part (logo at the bottom).

The marking tells us:

1. marking band: unidirectional type
2. 1st line: 200A -> google 200A vishay diode turns up: [datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88367/p4sma.pdf#page=2)
3. 2nd line: 06A -> [datecode](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88912/diodesgroupbodymarking.pdf#page=4): 2010, June in factory A (wherever that is)

Another hint to support this finding is the component name on the board. TRSB is an abbreviation for transorb diode which is a transient voltage suppressor, so we probably found the right thing.

Conclusion: It's a P4SMA200A. For purchase of this type have a look at [Vishay distributors](http://www.vishay.com/company/contacts/) which are available in your region.

Answer (score 1):

Its a P4SMA200A Transient suppresion diode.

Looked for some info here: http://www.ecadata.de/

Then on the datasheet: You can find "200A"  [Here](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88367/p4sma.pdf)

You can buy for example from [Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Littelfuse/P4SMA200A/?qs=JJML70Qc14sxEBez29Oqvg%3D%3D) or [DigiKey](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/P4SMA200A/P4SMA200ACT-ND/2770337?WT.srch=1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tested it with a multi meter (Continuity) and its beeps in both directions. I am guessing that its not right, am i correct?

Comment: @NirCarmona are you measuring that in circuit or on the component alone? If it's on the component alone it's not ok, inside the circuit there might be other current paths available to fool your continuity mode.

Comment: Measuring on the component alone.

Comment: @NirCarmona then it seems to have failed in short circuit (you could try to measure the resistance in both directions which will give you a better value to judge).

Comment: If it failed in circuit other things could have problems as well, merely replacing it may not solve all issues